# Programatically placing marker in drilldown map amchart

Tags: amcharts

I have a map which is a drilldown map. It goes from continents view to a country view.
My goal is to place markers dynamically based on the selected country (after the drilldown).

Here in this example I want to place a marker in Berlin (Germany) however this marker doesn't get created.

Example: https://codepen.io/ms92o/pen/gjMPEJ?editors=1111

```
var map = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "map",
    "theme": "light",

    "areasSettings": {
        "autoZoom": true,
        "rollOverOutlineColor": "#9a7bca",
        "selectedColor": "#9a7bca",
        "color": "#a791b4",
        "rollOverColor": "#9a7bca"
    },

    "zoomControl": {
        "buttonFillColor": "#a6bd7f",
        "buttonRollOverColor": "#9a7bca"
    },

    "dataProvider": continentsDataProvider,
    "objectList": {
        "container": "listdiv"
    },
    "listeners": [{
        "event": "clickMapObject",
        "method": function (event) {
            console.log(event);
            // TODO: how to create some markers here based on the selected country?
            let rep = { title: 'Berin', latitude: '52.520', longitude: '13.409779' };
            rep.svgPath = targetSVG;
            rep.zoomLevel = 3;
            rep.scale = 1.2;
            rep.label = rep.title;
            map.dataProvider.images.push(rep);
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the map's [`validateNow()`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmMap#validateNow)/[`validateData()`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmMap#validateData) methods whenever you update the map with new areas/markers or changes to its properties. The caveat of these calls is that they reset the map's zoom position unless you modify the dataProvider's zoom properties ([`zoomLevel`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/MapData#zoomLevel), [`zoomLatitude`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/MapData#zoomLatitude) and [`zoomLongitude`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/MapData#zoomLongitude)), which also affects the home button unless you reset them after the fact.

Here's a solution that adds the marker while making sure the zoom level sticks and fixes the home button afterward:

```
"listeners": [{
    "event": "clickMapObject",
    "method": function (event) {

        let rep = { title: 'Berin', latitude: '52.520', longitude: '13.409779' };
        rep.svgPath = targetSVG;
        rep.zoomLevel = 3;
        rep.scale = 1.2;
        rep.label = rep.title;
        map.dataProvider.images.push(rep);
        //delay the update so that the click+zoom action still occurs before
        //adding the marker
        setTimeout(function() {
          //preserve current zoom level on update
          map.dataProvider.zoomLevel = map.zoomLevel();
          map.dataProvider.zoomLatitude = map.zoomLatitude();
          map.dataProvider.zoomLongitude = map.zoomLongitude();
          map.validateNow(); //add marker

          //reset the zoom values so that the home button zooms 
          //completely out when clicked
          map.dataProvider.zoomLevel = 0;
          map.dataProvider.zoomLatitude = undefined;
          map.dataProvider.zoomLongitude = undefined;
        }, (map.zoomDuration + .5) * 1000); 
    }
}]
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/55654f089ce083f6c213e089dbd18d77/?editors=0010)